# PHP Carbon switches timezone offsets

Tags: php, php-carbon, timezone-offset

Using PHP 7.3 and nesbot/carbon 2.19.0 I run the following code:

```
$dt = new Carbon('2019-04-08T04:12:38.000000+00:00', 'UTC');
$local = $dt->copy()->setTimezone('Etc/GMT-9');
$formatted = $local->toISOString(true);
```

Now I see that `$formatted` now equals `2019-04-08T13:12:38.000000+09:00`. Why is my timezone offset now positive? Shouldn't it be negative? Strangely enough, if I `setTimezone('Etc/GMT+9')` then my offset becomes negative. Am I misunderstanding this or if not, any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: The result is correct. Etc/GMT-9 has a Offset +09:00. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Comment: Thanks! I will accept this as an answer if you are willing to post it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result is correct. Etc/GMT-9 has a Offset +09:00. [See List of tz database time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).